# How to access field result from returned controller in MVC .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await, xunit

Whilst my controller functions correctly, I am getting a syntax error in my **unit test** on the "Assert" line for `.Name`

> IAction result does not contain a definition for "Name"...

If I hover over "result" in debug mode I can see the data is in the result variable (Result > Model > Name). I've tried accessing it with Result.Model.Name but that's a syntax error also.

Unit test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestGetNameById()
    {
        string expectedName = "Component";

        using (var context = GetContextWithData())
        using (var controller = new AssetTypesController(context))
        {
            var result = await controller.Details(2);
            Assert.Equal(expectedName, result.Name);
        }
    }
```

Controller action:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var assetType = await _context.AssetType
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AssetTypeId == id);
        if (assetType == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(assetType);
    }
```

Model

```
public class AssetType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(databaseGeneratedOption: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `IActionResult` is not a type of `AssetType`.

Try something like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestGetNameById()
{
    string expectedName = "Component";

    using (var context = GetContextWithData())
    {
        var controller = new AssetTypesController(context);
        var result = await controller.Details(2) as ViewResult;
        var assetType = (AssetType) result.ViewData.Model;
        Assert.Equal(expectedName, assetType.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I don't quite understand why I couldn't do `AssetType assetType = result.ViewData.Model` - also do you have any idea why ReSharper gives me a warning for the "result" in result.ViewData.Model saying "possible System.NullReferenceException" ?

Comment: @egmfrs Probably because controller.Details(2) could be returned as null.

Comment: Changing to (ViewResult)await controller.Details(2); fixed the syntax warning, but then the unit test failed. I'll just leave it as it was.

Comment: Adding Assert.NotNull(result); directly after the var result line fixes the syntax warning.